# Can't connect to Android hot-spot: Invalid password

Tags: wifi, high-sierra

Today, my MacBook Pro (mid-2012) running High Sierra has decided to fail to connect to the hot-spot from my phone which is located a few feet away. It claims this is due to an `Invalid password.` I've verified that the password I've given it is the correct one for the network. A Linux machine in the same room is able to connect using that same password.

I've taken the steps recommended in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/280731/80135): removing the Wi-Fi service, rebooting, and re-adding the Wi-Fi service. That did not help. I changed the network password on both the Android and the Mac; this also did not help.  I've also changed the Wi-Fi network and password since rebooting.

#### Edit: since posting my question I have been able to use the network for a while, and since then it has again stopped working.  I've switched over to Ethernet, which seems to be functioning correctly so far.

How can I make the Wi-Fi go?

Comment: Did you try to change the password?

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE: Yeah, it didn't help.  Updated the question with this information.

Comment: Did you try to connect to the Android phone with cable?  This used to be possible some years ago.  Now I don't know.

Comment: @PierreALBARÈDE Unfortunately that's not really an option for my usage pattern because I have to place the phone quite far from the laptop in order to get half-decent cell service.  I've also been having problems connecting to other networks so it does seem like something is up with the wifi on this machine.  I switched over to Ethernet yesterday (connecting to the hotspot via a second PC) and that has been working correctly so far.